# order for loop output command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, sorting

I'm using the following command to list some of my favorite videos in a directory (and redirect the output into a text file):

```
for %i in (*avi *.mkv *mp4) do @echo %~ni
```

I'd like to alphabetically order the output of this command. I think I'd probably use `sed` or `awk` or something under Linux, but I'm on Windows 7 here using the command prompt (and soon, a batch file).

How would I achieve this (without using some external program or language)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `sort`

```
(for %i in (*avi *.mkv *mp4) do @echo %~ni) | sort
```